# 8.5 Connections Per User with Yodlee

Tags: sql, apache, yodlee

I am working with a financial company.  We recently did a test of integrating Yodlee's API and allowing connections to the mid tier SQL servers.  We noticed their API had 1700 connections for 200 users.  Is that normal to have an 8.5 connections for each user?  Has anyone else seen this type of behavior?

Comment: Question isn't totally clear to me; e.g. what do mean by "the mid tier SQL servers"? Is that your own servers?

Answer (score 1):

Yodlee is a SAAS provider, so I am assuming you are referring to the calls made to Yodlee APIs and not DB connections.

It depends on how you integrate Yodlee APIs. The total number of calls made to Yodlee APIs may be 1700 for 200 users depending on the data set you are retrieving from Yodlee.